# Listening CocoaASyncSocket on iPhone receiving connection but new socket does not call delegate

Tags: iphone, ipad, asyncsocket

I'm trying to implement basic message pasing between two devices by specifying IPs.  When one device tells its listening socket to listen as follows:

```
UInt16 port = 59647;
NSError *err = nil;
[socket acceptOnPort:port error:&err];
```

The `didAcceptNewSocket` delegate is called correctly, and should return a new socket to the connecting IP:Port.  As far as I can tell it's doing this, however, the new socket should be then calling `didConnectToHost`, which as far as I can tell it is not.

`didConnectToHost` is implemented correctly, as the device which initiates the connection with its socket properly calls it after the connection has been established.

I'm not doing anything in `didAcceptNewSocket` aside from a few `NSLogs` and setting the old listening socket to the new one (as its not needed after, and having it assigned to a different variable before didn't change anything, nor should it).

**What could make my new socket on the listening side not call this delegate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a client and a server, it is important to realize that only the client will invoke the `socket:didConnectToHost:port:` delegate method as it is the client who connects to a host (not the other way around).

On the server, the `socket:didAcceptNewSocket:` delegate method is invoked with the listening socket as the first argument.

Comment: It's been ages since I actually did this, but this seems like sound reasoning in hindsight.